# Display User ID instead of Name or Username

Tags: customization

I have BuddyPress installed in my WordPress. I don’t want to display the name or username in the profile of member, instead just User ID, like below Avatar instead of member’s name it will just show user ID.

For example:

User ID: 550

This will be in both Members Page and individual profile page.

Note that I don’t want name fields hidden from registration page, a member will enter his/her name but it will be hidden on site so that members will not be able to see each other’s name.

Please guide. Thank you!

Comment: As this is quite a specific requirement, you need to find the template or code that generates those pages and see if there's a sensible way to hook in to the point the output is generated.

Comment: @mozboz can you help me please in doing this?

Comment: Anyone please??

Answer (score 0):

You may get more help on this question by asking the Buddypress community directly on their Support forum [here](https://buddypress.org/support/).

It looks like you will need to create new copies of the template files that drive these two pages and place them in your Theme folder. These will override the plugin code completely and put you in control of the content. This is important because if you edit the plugin code directly, it may revert to its original state when the plugin updates in future.

The link below describes how to create files in your Theme to override the standard Buddypress designs but you will need to research further as it doesn't answer every question.

[Buddypress template hierarchy](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/#a-detailed-look-at-theme-compatibilities-template-hierarchy)

Hopefully someone on Buddypress' forum will help you get there!